# InfoPath form using external SharePoint list data issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-services

I'm having an issue displaying data on an InfoPath 2013 form (hosted in a SharePoint 2013 library) which uses external data coming from a SharePoint list on the same site.

I'm using external data because it happens to be contract rates (which tend to change), and the data is used all over the form. I've created input fields, fields that multiply the corresponding input field by the rate (external data), and fields that calculate the totals.

The issue: the InfoPath form will work perfectly when previewed, but when I publish it to the SharePoint library and view it in the browser, rates (that rely on the external data in the SharePoint list) will not calculate, just shows "NaN". Any other calculated values on the form will work properly, however. If I try filling the form out through SharePoint but using the InfoPath Form Filler, the rates display correctly. The issue only happens when filling the form out in the browser.

Here was my exact process in creating the calculated fields:

1. Created field element with the Decimal (double) data type
2. Added the appropriate formula in the Default Value section (includes the formulas which used the lookup data)
3. Dropped the field onto the form table
4. Right clicked on the field, changed type to Calculated Value
5. Applied currency formatting on the field

I used this method instead of just creating Calculated Values directly, because apparently when you do that, you will get lots of errors when publishing to SharePoint.

I have tried:

- Deleting and republishing the form library.
- Bypassing the calculated field method altogether and just dragged the field containing the lookup directly on the form, (displays no value on the web form).
- Turning off the option to store a copy of the external data in the form template.
- Converted the external data format to legacy mode and back to the current mode.

I am somewhat new to InfoPath. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here? 
Will much appreciate any insight to this issue.

Comment: How did you add the external data source? 'Recieve Data' from a 'SharePoint or Library'? Not from a service, right? Also you're using InfoPath 2010/2013?

Comment: What kind of data you recive from an external list ? is that currency or decimal type of data ? are u using "data connection" to add your data from external list ? finally are you using any formula to your calculated value ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you are using the SharePoint library hosted form and want it to work properly on browser so please check compatibility settings for a form template

[Compatibility Settings Article 1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/infopath-help/specify-the-compatibility-settings-for-a-form-template-HA010031070.aspx)

[Compatibility Settings Article 2](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/infopath-help/introduction-to-browser-compatible-form-templates-HA010169339.aspx)

[Compatibility Settings Article 3](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/infopath-help/web-browser-compatibility-in-infopath-forms-services-HA010204085.aspx)

browser compatible features has to be activated at the very beginning

1. Go to `Tools > Form Options > Compatibility` and check `Browser compatibility`.
2. Go to the `Design Checker` to see if there are any `comparability issues`. If there are, address them to ensure the form will open correctly in the browser.
3. Republish the form to SharePoint, and then make sure to change the library's settings such that the form opens in the browser.

Good luck! Let us know how it goes.

Last as per my experience I prefer share-point list hosted form  try your all mentioned things on SharePoint list hosted form I hope you will not find any issue in browser functioning.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I tried checking the browser compatibility, and the Design Checker found no problems with the form. The thing is, the form publishes to SharePoint with no problems, and I can view it and fill it out- the problem is that calculated values that involve external SharePoint lists do not seem to work in the browser (while the rest of the values work perfectly). All calculated values work outside of the browser.

Comment: Try Using sharepoint list form and check for result

Comment: The form template is a standard Web form...what do you mean by sharepoint list form?

Comment: You are publishing the form to library customize it to publish it at some list.